# Cannot remove GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension service from launchd

Tags: terminal, network, permission, launchd, anti-virus

**ref:** [Consent needed to enable ENSM Firewall 10.7.5 and later](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB93600)

This system extension was left over from a McAfee LiveSafe install that I had removed using the provided uninstaller.

I had to disable it from Network Settings to prevent the hard crashing that began to occur after installing another antivirus product. I eventually removed it completely with the **`-`** button.

[image: Doesn't like Bitdefender]

**system.log** is flooded with these entries

```
Sep 29 19:54:25 macbroke com.apple.xpc.launchd[2] (GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

There were some *mcafee* entries left over in **disabled.plist**, so made sure to disable them

```
$ grep -rnw '/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd/' -e "mcafee"  
/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd//disabled.plist:7:    <key>com.mcafee.genutility</key>
/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd//disabled.plist:17:   <key>com.mcafee.datupdate</key>
/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd//disabled.plist:19:   <key>com.mcafee.virusscan.fmpd</key>
/var/db/com.apple.xpc.launchd//disabled.plist:21:   <key>com.mcafee.productupdate</key>
```

I was also able to *successfully run* **`disable`** on the network extension, though **launchd** continued to run it, according to system.log

```
sudo launchctl disable system/GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension

$ launchctl print-disabled system  
disabled services = {
    "com.mcafee.genutility" => true
    "com.mcafee.datupdate" => true
    "com.mcafee.virusscan.fmpd" => true
    "com.mcafee.CMF.networkextensionn" => true
    "com.mcafee.productupdate" => true
    "GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension" => true
}
```

I then attempted to **`remove`** the network extension, but was given a *"not privileged"* error

```
sudo launchctl remove GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension

Sep 29 12:22:19 macbroke com.apple.xpc.launchd[2] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system): Caller not allowed to perform action: launchctl.642, action = service remove, code = 1: Operation not permitted, uid = 0, euid = 0, gid = 0, egid = 0, asid = 100007
```

**`unload`** gave an *"Input/output error"*

```
sudo launchctl unload system/GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension
```

**`print`** revealed the location of the service module

```
launchctl print system/GT8P3H7SPW.com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension

program = /Library/SystemExtensions/D61ECA19-7AC8-43FF-98C0-A3FE84132C34/com.mcafee.CMF.networkexte
nsion.systemextension/Contents/MacOS/com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension
```

[image]

**Would removing this file/directory cause launchd to stop trying to schedule it?** I realize that the scheduling of a service is probably independent of its binaries existing or not, but figured it may be worth a try.

Even with **`sudo`** I do not have privileges to rename the parent directory under */Library/SystemExtensions*, but could possibly from **Recovery**. However this would require mounting the primary partition which I think I had trouble with a while back when creating a manual image with **hdiutil**.

---

Opening *embedded.provisionprofile* with <kbd>command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

[image]

Previewing *embedded.provisionprofile* with <kbd>space</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at the output of `systemextensionsctl list`? `systemextensionsctl uninstall` might be able to deal with it.

Comment: It did, after a quick `csrutil disable` in recovery. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a lot like a *Network Filter* which I believe is a kind of *System Extension*.
You should take a look at the output of `systemextentionsctl list` and construct a command similar to this:

`systemextensionsctl uninstall CT8P3H7SPW com.mcafee.CMF.networkextension`

Depending on your OS, you may need to first disable *SIP* by booting into recovery and running `csrutil disable`. Don't forget to re-enable it afterwards.

Comment: I'm now left wondering whether the `launchctl` commands would have ran successfully after disabling SIP. Regardless, Im betting that`systemextentionsctl` is cleaner. The man page only has a few lines.